# Переопределение в двух анонимных классах сразу

Tags: java

Как тут работают анонимные классы?

```
Class aClass = new Class(), aClass2 = new Class(){ 
    @Override 
    public void run(){ 
    System.out.println("Thread"); 
    } 
};
```

Допустим у меня есть класс который запускает доп поток, и при создании двух классов запустится два потока, но при создании анонимного класса лишь один метод будет переопределён. Как можно два метода сразу переопределить?

Comment: Не могу это воспроизвести. `Class` - это `public final class Class<T>` из пакета `java.lang`?

Answer (score 1):

Если java 8+, то задайте лямбду

```
Runnable r = ()->System.out.println("Thread");
```

Если без лямбд, то через анонимный класс

```
Runnable r = new Runnable(){     
    @Override 
    public void run(){ 
     System.out.println("Thread"); 
    } 
}
```

А затем вызывайте функцию в классе.

```
Class aClass2 = new Class(){ 
    @Override 
    public void run(){ 
     r.run();
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ

```
  Class aClass = new Class(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Thread");
        }
    }, aClass2 = new Class(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Thread");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Через запятую нечитабельно, сбивает  с толку %)

Comment: И DRY нарушели.